# javascript userscript to encode pdf into base64

Tags: javascript, base64, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to build a userscript to auto print PDFs using print node. The files can not be accessed without a session based login which printnode can not support. So the other option is to base64 encode the file in the browser and POST it to the API endpoint.

`https://example.com/InternalReport.php?id=417660` is the page I am running this on, which just returns a PDF file that the browser displays by default.

I was able to manually convert the file, and send it like this, im trying to figure out how to get the file which is the page, but not end up encoding the entire display html, just the PDF itself.

```
fetch(https://api.printnode.com/printjobs, {
    method:"POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        printerId: "71635092",
        contentType: "pdf_base64",
        content: "JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjQgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZ...g0KMTE2DQolJUVPRg0K"
        })
    }).then(result => {
        // do something with the result
        console.log("Completed with result:", result);
    }).catch(err => {
        // if any error occured, then catch it here
        console.error(err);
    });
```

I tried (I think, I deleted my first attempts by accident) `base64.encode(Document.body)` in the content but print node did not understand the content. I think that actually sent all the HTML of the displayed page including chromes built in viewer. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I am using tamper monkey to embed this in the resulting page, I dont have control over the source otherwise I would obviously do this from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's Chrome, the tab is showing a dummy document where the contents of the PDF is embedded inside an internal plugin/extension, so you'll have to download the pdf again:

```js
(async () => {
  const blob = await (await fetch(location)).blob();
  const fr = new FileReader();
  const dataUrl = await new Promise(resolve => {
    fr.onload = () => resolve(fr.result);
    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
  fetch('https://api.printnode.com/printjobs', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      // ...................
      content: dataUrl.slice(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1),
    }),
  });
})();
```

Comment: I had thought of this option but I could not figure out how to make it happen, I filled in the rest including the console log reporting, but it never seems to get to the fetch part. Im not getting any errors. Just never seems to finish

Comment: Examine the request in devtools network panel and see which headers differ compared to the original request for pdf in the tab. In case the original request is opened in a new tab you can use `chrome://net-export` or try enabling `Autoopen devtools for popups` in devtools settings.

Comment: I only see the initial request headers and the favicon. https://prnt.sc/cyx9llQNMb5F nothing else seems to be waiting or failing to load. I assume I should see a second load of the document.

Comment: It means there's no PDF file. The server renders it as DOM elements e.g. images, canvas, text.

Comment: Its Content-Type: application/pdf in the headers, but the URL is a .php which I assume generates the PDF on the fly.

Comment: I added a console log line to the beginning of the async, it never gets triggered.

Comment: So the arrow method seems to be the problem, I made the async a function called getpdf and called it in a console log line so the output writes to the log and the entire function works! I dont fully understand why this does not work, Im thinking the outer parentheses are possibly the problem.

Comment: The code is correct and should work in Chrome newer than v55. I guess it may be a copypaste problem or your previous code doesn't end on `;` (semicolon).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249174/discussion-between-jpaytonwpd-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 0):

Based on wOxxOm's answer I was able to make this work within a userscript. The arrow method does not seem to work for some reason, maybe because of its in a userscript. But this works:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Print Node test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://example.com/InternalReportWorkOrder.php?*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("PRINT_NODE_API_KEY:"));
    console.log("Started:", headers);
    async function getpdf() {
        console.log("async started");
        const blob = await (await fetch(location)).blob();
        const fr = new FileReader();
        const dataUrl = await new Promise(resolve => {
            fr.onload = () => resolve(fr.result);
            fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
        fetch('https://api.printnode.com/printjobs', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                printerId: "PRINTER_ID",
                contentType: "pdf_base64",
                content: dataUrl.slice(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1),
            }),
        }).then(result => {
            // do something with the result
            console.log("Completed with result:", result);
        }).catch(err => {
            // if any error occured, then catch it here
            console.error(err);
        });
    };
    console.log(getpdf());
})();
```